# Sharing a part of an array in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi, sparse-matrix, scatter

I am thinking about a problem that requires sharing an array as follows:

Suppose `int array[10]` and there are `3 processes` so that;

```
process 0 gets array[0:3] 3 is included.
process 1 gets array[3:6] 6 is included.
process 2 gets array[6:9] 9 is included.
```

However I am not sure how to split this array between processes like this. To be more specific, this array is for `Sparse Matrix in CSR format`, and array represents rows.

How can I figure this out in MPI C/C++.

Comment: `MPI_Scatterv()`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet can you elaborate how to use that? I know it puts strides between elements but I am not sure how to use that in this concept.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, according to the documentation, `MPI_Scatterv` cannot be used to scatter overlapping ranges.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to scatter overlapping ranges?

Comment: @Evg actually when there are 9 rows and 3 processes, each process get 3 rows. However, we add one additional element so that each process knows where to stop. That is why there are 10 elements in the array and each process gets 4 elements.

Comment: `MPI_Scatterv` is not guaranteed to work with overlapping ranges (though it [may work in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582696/mpi-python-scatterv-and-overlapping-data) - this requirement has its root in `MPI_Gatherv` where it makes perfect sense). You can manually send each subrange to each process. It might be not optimal but is guaranteed to work.

Comment: So `MPI_Scatterv()` has to be invoked twice in order to achieve the expected result while respecting the MPI standard :-)

Comment: @Evg you mean sending ranges through MPI_Send from Master thread? In that example, it seems working but I am confused about the role of displs. Is it for the starting index? or stride?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet can you provide a pseducode or a decription about how I can achieve my goal with two Scatterv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-standard-conforming implementation using `MPI_Scatterv`:

```
int arr[10];
const int counts[] = {4, 4, 4};
const int displs[] = {0, 3, 6};

int recv_buff[4];
MPI_Scatterv(arr, counts, displs, MPI_INT, recv_buff, 
    4, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

`displs` are just simple offsets and are specified as follows:

```
Original array arr[10]:
[ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
  ^ displs[0]
        ^ displs[1]
              ^ displs[2]
```

This is not guaranteed to work because subarrays [overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36582696):

> The specification of counts, types, and displacements should not cause any location on the `root` to be read more than once.

As **Gilles Gouaillardet** noted in comments, to avoid overlaps you can call `MPI_Scatterv` twice:

```
int arr[10];
const int counts1[] = {4, 0, 4};
const int counts2[] = {0, 4, 0};
const int displs[]  = {0, 3, 6};

int recv_buff[4];
MPI_Scatterv(arr, counts1, displs, MPI_INT, recv_buff, 
    counts1[rank], MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Scatterv(arr, counts2, displs, MPI_INT, recv_buff, 
    counts2[rank], MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Alternatively, you can use plain `MPI_Send`s/`MPI_Get`s.

Comment: So, displs is basically the starting point of each rank?  Btw, I like this approach.

Comment: @HarunSasmaz Yes, process `i` receives the subarray that starts at `arr + displs[i]` and has length of `counts[i]`.